# Java probablePrime performance

Tags: java, performance, biginteger

Javadoc on [probablePrime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#probablePrime%28int,%20java.util.Random%29):

> Returns a positive BigInteger that is probably prime, with the
>   specified bitLength. The probability that a BigInteger returned by
>   this method is composite does not exceed 2-100.

My question is, how much performance does this gain by not guaranteeing a prime number, but making it almost certain? Also, is this performance difference really worth the minute chance of a bug occurring at some time in the future? Especially if the validity of encryption depends on this number being prime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the heart of `probablePrime()` is a series of [Miller-Rabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) tests (The number of rounds performed depends on the bit size of the number) combined with a [Lucas-Lehmer primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test). The time complexity of these depend quite a bit on the rest of the `BigInteger` implementation. Taking in "slow" estimates from wikipedia would be O(k log(n)^3) and O(log(n)^3) respectively.

On the other hand, the [AKS-primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test), without unproven conjectures, can run in Õ(log(n)^6).

So assuming your numbers are large enough, the probabilistic test can be quite a bit faster than a deterministic one. For anything large enough for cryptography the asymptotic behaviour is quite likely observable. Of course, the only way to find out for certain is to implement the modified AKS and time the results.

(`k` is the number of cycles in Mille-Rabin).

Answer (score 1):

If you have this:

> Especially if the validity of encryption depends on this number being
>   prime

kind of constraint then you should not use `probablePrime` in my opinion. Because you cannot guarantee the correctness of your algorithm.

**But** if the probability of getting a non-prime is so low that is comparable for example to an [SHA-1 collision probability](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-1.html) then you are OK with it. (If git is ok with it so you are)

If you are using a pool of prime numbers in a given range then you can just pre-generate a list of prime numbers and put them in a lookup table. this will give you `O(1)` time complexity.

Comment: That's a good edit, I guess if the chance of cracking encryption assuming a prime number, is better than the chance of us producing a composite number, then we really lose nothing at the end of the day. Also, encryption is probably the reason this method even exists, generating large primes is `almost` exclusive to encryption

Comment: I would still like to know how much this actually speeds up performance. Do you have any insight into that?

Comment: Also turns out that BigInteger has a contructor for this where you can specify certainty: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(int,%20int,%20java.util.Random) so if you have a higher-bit encryption algorithm, you can stop this method from being your weakest list. Conversely you could also use this increase the probability of a composite, when this is an "overly strong link" compared to the rest of the algorithm to increase performance.

Comment: When you don't want to look for really big numbers I think you can get away with `O(n log n)` complexity using a sieve-based algorithm. Otherwise you have something around `O(n^2)`. I don't know the asymptotic time complexity of `probablePrime` but my guess based on the api is something between `O(n log n)` and `O(n)`.  Don't take it for granted. You have many ways to calculate primes. Check out [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10683/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-generating-n-th-prime-number) and the wikipedia page for primes.

Comment: "If you are using a pool of prime numbers in a given range then you can just pre-generate a list of prime numbers and put them in a lookup table. this will give you O(1) time complexity." I'm not sure if this is sufficient for encryption, given the giant size of numbers, it would simply take up too much memory. Also I don't think you could compute the lookup table for the needed range in a persons lifetime

Comment: I see. The problem is that you don't provide enough information in your question. I need concrete data in order to answer your question. ;)

Comment: The problem with the pool is that you need a prime unknown to anybody else. So you have to generate it yourself. So pooling means generating N primes instead of one. IMHO, not exactly a speed up. :D

Comment: It is definitely a speedup because you trade time complexity to space complexity (by creating a lookup for primes). A lookup is persisted between calls to the prime function of course. It was unbeknownst to me before that the OP has the constraint you were talking about.